# Считать данные из *.xls в *.xml с помощью C#

Tags: c#, xml, xls

Всем доброго времени суток! Нужна помощь, сам не успеваю, да и знаний нет.
Нет, мне не нужен код и полностью написанная программа - хотелось бы узнать, почитать, поломать голову и сделать самому.

Сама суть проблемы:

**Что имеется:** файл Excel 97-2003 года. Простенькая, маленькая(6*10) с некоторыми данными.

**Необходимо:** с помощью C# конвертировать этот файл в xml с некоторыми условиями, которые являются обязательными.

Пример выходного и исходного файла приложил, текст задачи и условия.
[Файлы](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoWPNFpK_C-tga1pE0BB6O0Tgu78Mw?e=zYJu1E)
 [image: Задача и условие]
[image: Исходный файл]
**По тому, что я смог нарыть сам:**

Есть некие библиотеки, типа Open XML и основанные на ней, но, как узнал только недавно - они не поддерживают форматы 2003 года. 
Есть Office COM Interop - вроде с помощью этого средства можно, правда писали что она немного заторможена.
Было немного информации и про другие, но исчерпывающую информацию по тому что я искал - не нашел.

**В связи с этим - вопросы:**

*Как реализовать конвертер на с# используя командную строку?*  Чтобы было понятно почему я делаю через командную строку - я только начал изучать язык. Командную строку я хотя бы знаю определенные команды и все такое, а вот с WPF и Win.Forms еще не знаком.

*Что лучше использовать и какие библиотеки?* если можно ссылки на док-ию желательно на русском, еще один язык я не осилю...

Ну и в общем, куда копать, и что почитать на эту тему ? Сейчас пока пытаюсь реализовать хотя бы считывание данных с Excel через "Interop". А о том, как я буду передавать данные в xml даже не задумывался еще...

Comment: По-моему, Вы немного ошиблись. Тут как бы не сервис добрых услуг "Сделаем за Вас"... тем более что для сохранения XLS в XML никакого c# в принципе не нужно.

Comment: Я и не просил сделать что-то за меня. У меня просьба направить, указать, что нужно для этого. А Вам бы читать внимательнее - потому как задача стоит именно таким образом - через С#

Comment: Для этого нужно ознакомиться хотя бы со штатной библиотекой для работы с XML (описание есть почти в любом учебнике и в гугле полно статей найдёте). Также Вам потребуется библиотека для работы с Office. Можно начать со стандартной Interop, которую Вы и используете.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, зачем тут XML-библиотека. Тем более что требуется строго определённая структура. Вот в разы проще открыть файл через ADO и скопировать в формат XML тупо как в текстовый файл. По крайней мере хотя бы можно гарантировать, что получится строго то, что нужно, без библиотечной самодеятельности (бывало уже, проходили).

Comment: Ну вот видите - для вас это уже понятно и проще, для меня же - непроходимый лес не пойми чего...
ADO еще даже не встречал нигде.

Comment: 1) Если у вас найдётся .xlsx файл, то посоветую распарсить этот файл с помощью **EPPlus**, а создать .xml документ при помощи **System.Xml.Linq**

2) Если всё же нужно работать именно с .xls, то обратите внимание на этот вопрос, тут автор хорошо описал инструменты: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic

Comment: Вам лучше с таким вопросом идти на форум. Либо разбивать данный вопрос на несколько!